# Excel to PHP array, possible and how?

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I have a big excel file that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to put each row into an array.

Is this possible to access the first row's `order id` like this?

```
$result[0][2] // returns 7432
```

Assuming the actual first row that gives prefix for the columns' name is not present.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Save the spreadsheet as a CSV, then use PHP's built-in CSV functions. See the sample code here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: This does not answer the question. It's asked to read Excel directly, not CSV.

Comment: Although it does not answer, in a literal way, the question, it solves the problem, though.

Answer (score 24):

I  recommended to use PHPEXCEL library

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

you can see an [example](http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/07/16/phpexcel-advanced-read-write-excel-made-simple/)

**Update:**
Now the alternative to this library is [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: looks like PHPExcel - DEAD

Answer (score 9):

May be my answer is too simple (for one time work only), but I use the CONCATENATE "Function" in excell. 
The last cell on each row will have concatenation function, like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("['";A2;"'=>['data1' => '";B2;"', 'data2' => '";C2;"'],")
```

where:

```
column "A" is ID of something;
column "B" is first characteristic;
column "C" is second characteristic;
etc.
```

Then just copy and paste function results to Your script or config file,  and do not forget the first and the last bracket.

Comment: CONCATENATE ftw! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
$content = file_get_contents($your_file_path); 
$lines = array_map("rtrim", explode("\n", $content));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the PHPExcel library deprecated they've released "PhpSpreadsheet"

This will help [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @ÖmerAn Try this https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/